# Can't seem to get "keyup" to work

Tags: javascript, keyup

I'm trying to replicate something I've seen on a few blogs and is somewhat used on Facebook, and that's moving to the next post by pressing a key.  On Facebook it's pressing the "j" key.  I'm not very good at Javascript, and have found a few articles on here in regards to how to do it, but I feel like I'm missing something.  Here's my View code, please show me what I'm doing wrong.  The alerts aren't even firing.  Thanks.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<script>
    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        alert("entered function");
        if (e.keyCode == 90 || e.keyCode == 16) {
            alert("entered conditional");
            var ta = document.getElementsByClassName('post_unread')[0];
            ta.removeAttribute('class', 'post_unread');
            ta.addAttribute('class', 'post_reading');
        }
    });
</script>

<div>
    <div class="forum_post_wrapper">
        <div class="forum_post">

        </div>
        <div class="forum_post_wrapper">
            <div class="forum_post post_unread">

            </div>
            <div class="forum_post_wrapper">
                <div class="forum_post post_unread">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot document.ready !

Comment: @adeneo What does that matter? The event is bound to `document`

Comment: @Ian - oh, didn't notice, just noticed the markup after the event handler. Should probably learn to read.

Comment: This should work fine. Is jQuery loaded properly?

Comment: @adeneo Haha no big deal. I had to double-take because as soon as you said that, I was like "oh yeah, you need that....wait, no you don't" :)

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue -- the alerts fire just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/T64fv/

Comment: Quick question - you're using jQuery, but why is `$(document).keyup(` your only jQuery code? `document.getElementsByClassName` and `removeAttribute` can be done more compatibly in jQuery. And `addAttribute` doesn't exist...did you mean `setAttribute`?

Comment: `$('.post_unread').eq(0).toggleClass('post_reading post_unread');`

Comment: @Ian - Issue was that while VS2012 had the jquery-1.8.2.min.js file in the project, it wasn't loaded in the _Layout.cshtml file.  The user's answer below pointed me in that direction, I've added it to the layout file, and it works fine now.  Thanks.

Comment: @Ian - Honestly, I'm just winging it here, so I thought that since there was a "removeAttribute", there would be an add.  Since it's a side project, I haven't put too much into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you imported the jQuery file, the reason ***why I ask is you've not tagged with jQuery***

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" />
```

Maybe you missed to add this script.

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) { // this belongs to jQuery
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  VS2012 had it loaded to the project, but it wasn't in the _Layout.cshtml.  It works.

Comment: @XstreamINsanity I'm glad that I was able to help you.

Comment: The reason I didn't tag with jQuery was because when I looked up "javascript keyup" on Google, from my glimpsing over, it looked as though it was something that didn't necessarily belong to jQuery, but javascript.  I should read things more thoroughly some times.  :)

Comment: @XstreamINsanity Usually happens, no problem.  People here in SO will point you in the right direction :) Thanks for sharing the fix that you made.